# Separate Character from date on filename sql expression

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, expression

I just wondering how to separate the character from the filename using SQL Expression for example Filename is IED_2015Nov020914.AF I want to separate or split the "Date" Which is "2015Nov02" in the where clause of SQL Expression.. I try to use function called "cross apply" But no luck it not working here is my working so far

```
where (patindex('%[0-9]%', File_name) > "2018-Nov-12"));
```

Thank you

Comment: 1) Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL? 2) Does your filename has constant format?

Comment: All values starts with `IED_` and ends with `914.AF`? Provide more samples.

Comment: The easiest way is to locate `_` char + substring 9 characters. But it depend of filename format

Comment: @ Stanislovas Kalašnikovas // For IED_ Yes but for 0914 is the time

Comment: You can use this but totally depends on the string format - 
`DECLARE @s nvarchar(20) = 'IED_2015Nov020914.AF'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@s,CHARINDEX('_',@s)+1,9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to locate `_` char and substring `9` characters.

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(filename VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab VALUES ('IED_2015Nov020914.AF');

SELECT SUBSTRING(filename, CHARINDEX('_',filename)+1, 9) AS result
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383604)**</kbd>

Warning: This will work only if your data has constant format:
`...._yyyyMMMdd....`

If you need you can `CAST` result to date:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(filename, CHARINDEX('_',filename)+1, 9) AS DATE) AS result
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383607)**</kbd>